# A question about parsing this complex passage

Tags: syntax, parsing

The passage in question is an excerpt from a novel.

Background info: B is an inventor who works for the government in the story's universe and has created his own  mechanism in secret that is capable of gathering various information on the public (their identity, whereabouts, activity etc.) that surpasses the mechanisms the government already uses. A is his assistant.

> A: it's only natural a mechanism invented by you would surpass the others currently in use. Though, I wonder what could have possibly occurred that caused you to invent your own mechanism?
>
> B (ケン): Putting your trust in things so easily is a foolish act that lowers our performance. そこは『足りぬ脳味噌で熟考を重ねて検証もしたが、やはりケンの造り上げた機構の方が全てにおいて上だ』と言い給え。

I'm having troubles parsing the part I left untranslated in B's dialogue.

I tried breaking it down like so:

> そこは~と言い給え - to say here that ~
>
> 足りぬ脳味噌で - [with/through/by using] inadequate brainpower.
>
> 熟考を重ねて検証もしたが - carefully considering re-examination too, but~
>
> やはりケンの造り上げた機構の方が全てにおいて上だ - as expected, a mechanism created by Ken is better in everything.

It's hard to see how this all fits together.

I would be so grateful if someone could correct me where I've gone wrong!

Comment: It looks like you are loosely translating A's dialogue, not B's, unless ケン refers to himself in the third-person. Also, I don't think 足りぬ脳味噌 means what you think it means. Maybe use 技能 or 知力.

Comment: ケン doesn't usually refer to himself in third person, he uses a regular pronoun to refer to himself under normal circumstances, but I didn't think anything of him mentioning his own name in the line above because he looks to be quoting something. Thanks I will analyze the sentence again with the vocab you suggested.

Comment: The reason I mentioned it is because the Japanese dialog in the topmost box seems to be closer to a translation of A's words, but is shown directly under B's reply. As they seem to be not so literally translated, it is a bit hard to tell. Sorry if I'm misreading something. One more suggestion for brainpower: 知能 (intelligence).

Comment: 「そこは~と言い給え。」って、命令文ですけど・・・「to say here that ~」って命令ですか？

Comment: It seems like b (Ken) is simply telling a what to say (the part within 『』) , and thus it makes perfect sense to talk about himself in third person. It would help if you provided us with the original text as well and not just your interpretation. This is especially important when there might be subtle nuances that you might be missing... This Ken person seems quite arrogant

Comment: Also, just a minor detail, but if you are writing in the form A: text B: text etc, don't use quotation mark around the text that they are saying as this is already implied from the structure. If you put quotation marks there, it is as if the speakers are quoting someone.